# Use lodash to find a matching value if it exists

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have the following:

```
 myArray = [{
        "urlTag": "Google",
        "urlTitle": "Users",
        "status": 6,
        "nested": {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "http:\/\/www.google.com",
        }
    },
    {
        "urlTag": "Bing",
        "tabTitle": "BingUsers"
    }]
```

I have `myUrlTagToSearch = "Yahoo"`, I want to loop through `myArray`, check if any `urlTag` is equal to `"Yahoo"`, if yes: return `"Yahoo"`, if not: just return a empty string (`""`). In this example, it should return `""` because there are only `"Google"` and `"Bing"`.

Can I do this with lodash?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [lodash's `find()` method](https://lodash.com/docs#find) mixed with a regular conditional (`if`) statement to do this.

For starters, to search the array, you can use:

```
var result = _.find(myArray, { "urlTag": "Yahoo" });
```

*You can replace `"Yahoo"` with your `myUrlTagToSearch` variable here.*

If no matches are found it'll return `undefined`, otherwise it'll return the matching `Object`. As Objects are *truthy* values and `undefined` is a *fasley* value, we can simply use `result` as the condition within an `if` statement:

```
if (result)
    return "Yahoo";
else
    return "";
```

---

We don't even need to define `result` here, as we can simply use:

```
if ( _.find(myArray, { "urlTag": "Yahoo" }) )
    return "Yahoo";
else
    return "";
```

Or even:

```
return _.find(myArray, { "urlTag": "Yahoo" }) ? "Yahoo" : "";
```

Comment: Since you're using `find()` to check for existence, rather than actually using the result, you might want to use [some()](https://lodash.com/docs#some). It does a little less work than `find()`.

Answer (score 3):

You probably *can* do this with lodash (I don't know much about lodash), but in case no-one else answers there is a simple vanilla JS solution:

```
function exists(site) {
    return myArray.some(function (el) {
      return el.urlTag === site;
    }) === false ? '': site;
}

exists('Yahoo');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/v21yoqqa/1/)